# Object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne is not callable",…

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to save data in my user model and then save data to user  related model ( User , Profile )

this is my code

Use Has one Profile

Profile Belongs to User

```
        try {
        $model=new Model([
            'username'=>$request->username,
            'password'=>bcrypt($request->password),
            'department_id'=>$department
        ]);
        $model->assignRole($role);
        $model->profile()([
           'name'=>$request->name,
           'family'=>$request->family,
           'email'=>$request->email,
           'field_id'=>$request->field,
           'phone'=>$request->phone,
           'address'=>$request->address,
        ]);
        return $model->save()?Responder::userCreatedSuccess($model):Responder::userDoesNotCrated();
```

Comment: Which of these lines throws the error? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Please post a stack trace in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$model->profile()([
```

you should use

```
$model->profile()->create([
```